# multi class inheritance setup issues

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have 3 interface (pure virtual) classes like this

```
class A {
    virtual void M1() = 0;
    virtual void M2() = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    virtual void M3() = 0;
};

class C : public A {
    virtual void M4() = 0;
};
```

I have the implementers like this

```
class Aimpl : A {
    void M1 () override {};
    void M2 () override {};
}

class Bimpl: public Aimpl, public B{
     void M3() override {};
}

class Cimpl: public Aimpl, public C{
     void M4() override {};
}
```

and

```
Bimpl b = Bimpl();
b.M2() // Error. M2 is ambigous. Can be from Aimpl or A
```

what's a simple way to fix this? I want to be able to pass around B or C in functions rather than Bimpl

Comment: no. public. forgot the keyword there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you have two different `M2` methods in `Bimpl`:  `Aimpl::M2` and `B::M2`.  You have run into the [diamond-inheritance problem](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html).

To fix it, you should use virtual inheritance.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403842) provides a very good overview.  Essentially, you should use something like this:

```
class A {
    virtual void M1() = 0;
    virtual void M2() = 0;
};

class B : public virtual A {
    virtual void M3() = 0;
};

class C : public virtual A {
    virtual void M4() = 0;
};

class Aimpl : public virtual A {
    void M1 () override {};
    void M2 () override {};
};

class Bimpl: public virtual Aimpl, public virtual B {
     void M3() override {};
};

class Cimpl: public virtual Aimpl, public virtual C {
     void M4() override {};
};
```

Note that I'm not super super familiar with virtual inheritance, so this may or may not be the best way to apply virtual inheritance.

Comment: Compiles with clang but vc++ gives warnings that Cimpl inherits M1 by dominance and warnings are treated as errors in my project.

Comment: @randomThought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864550/c-inheritance-via-dominance-warning